# Размер кастомных иконок спиков css

Tags: html, css, icon, ul

Существует некий список, в котором обязательно нужны кастомные иконки, сделал их через `list-style-image: url(../img/gearwheel.png);`, все работает, но иконки слишком большие, как их уменьшить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, иконки слишком большие.

Comment: Эмм... уменьшить в редакторе размер самой картинки? о_О Как вариант, можно добавить `background-image: url(...)` на псевдоэлемент `li:before` — и уже ему задать размеры... или просто `<img>`

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с `before`

```css
ul {list-style: none;}

.custom-li {position: relative;}
.custom-li:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://gyazo.com/e353b01477115f655a179520e53b7b9c.png');
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px; height: 16px;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  left: -22px; top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="custom-li">bubu</li>
  <li class="custom-li">bubu</li>
  <li class="custom-li">bubu</li>
</ul>
```

(насколько понял, нет вариантов поменять размер картинки в `list-style-image`)

Comment: Спасибо, ваш способ полностью рабочий, но был найден чуть лучше вариант - менее громоздкий, спасибо

Comment: И да вы полность правы, размер иконки в `list-style-image` не изменить

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему при помощи использования псевдоэлемента `li:before` и FontAwesome:

```
.li-gearwheel:before {
  content: "\f013";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
  width: 1.3em;
}
```